# -webkit-background-clip problem or error show in vscode

Tags: css, sass

[problem to use -webkit-background-clip on vs-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lblN.png)

It works properly but get error sometime. Why does it happen?

Here is my code:

```
.heading-secondary{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $color-primary-light , $color-primary-dark );
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;  
    transition: all .2s;
```

**AND THE PROBLEM SHOW**

> Also define standard property 'background-clip'
> !error
> scss(vendorPrefix)

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full/minimal code needed to show the problem _in the question itself_, a description of what should happen, a description of what **does** happen instead, and quotes of any errors received. "it work properly but get error sometime" is not a usable problem description.

Comment: And please don't post images. Copy-paste code as text instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's self-explanatory. Include the `background-clip: text` property too.

Comment: Thanks That Solve and Work For me

Comment: Mind marking this as accepted/upvoting?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, it's not an *error* it's a *warning*. Nothing is broken. Visual Studio Code just gives you advise in the "problems" panel if they have the "warning" icon.

And since your property has a [vendor prefix](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/), the property is considered non-standard since it only works in one browser (engine). So it's highly recommended to always use them alongside with the non-prefixed property.